# Apple Push Notification - require a custom application to test?

Tags: ios, ios4, apple-push-notifications

When you setup your push notification server, and want to send a message to yourself to test  push notification.

Do you need to create a custom application in order to recieve the push notification messages?

OR

Does the push notification message just get sent to the device without any special application required? just like a SMS? (the message application is already built into the OS, is this the case with push notification?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application ID is a part of the required data for APN. You can't just poke a message out to a phone, you've got to do it on behalf of a particular application.

If you think about the way permissions are handled, it makes sense. Notification permission is handled on an app-by-app basis.

Comment: This would mean I would need to create an app, I can not just send a notification to the phone without my own app installed onto the phone first right? (at least that is what i understand)

Comment: That's right. Nothing to send a notification to without an app to receive it.